# Display information onto the form from the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

**SOLVED**

I am trying to make an edit form so that it automatically displays the information which is in the database onto the form.

At the moment it only seems to change the Product Details when edit is pressed for different products and seems like it only wants to show the first row in the database for example, id '1' instead of id '3' when the 3rd id is selected. Also the image does not seem to rename like it is supposed to.

Not too sure where im going wrong, i thought it was a simple fetch from the database but seems not to be.

edit.php

```
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['product_name'])) {

    $pid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thisID']);
    $product_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
    $price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);

    $details = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details']);
    $stock = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stock']);
    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    $sql = mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE products SET product_name='$product_name', price='$price', details='$details', category='$category', stock='$stock' WHERE id='$pid'");
    if ($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'] != "") {
        // Place image in the folder 
        $newname = "$pid.jpg";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "inventory_images/$newname");
    }
    header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
<?php 
// Gather this product's full information for inserting automatically into the edit form below on page
if (isset($_GET['pid'])) {
    $targetID = $_GET['pid'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$targetID' LIMIT 1");
    $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ 

             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $category = $row["category"];
             $details = $row["details"];
             $stock = $row["stock"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
        }
    } else {
        echo "Sorry it does not exist.";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
<?php 
// This block grabs the whole list for viewing
$product_list = "";
$sql = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC");
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $stock = $row["stock"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $product_list .= "Product ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> - &pound;$price - Stock: $stock -<em>Added $date_added</em> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a><br />";

    }
} else {
    $product_list = "You have no products listed in your store yet";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Stock List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
  <?php include_once("../customer/template_header.php");?>
  <div id="pageContent"><br />

<div class="center">
<div id="content">
  <div id="content_top"></div>

  <div id="content_main">
    <center>

    <div align="right" style="margin-right:32px;"><a href="inventory_list.php#inventoryForm">Add New Stock</a></div>
<div align="left" style="margin-left:24px;">
      <h2>Stock list</h2>
      <?php echo $product_list; ?>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <a name="inventoryForm" id="inventoryForm"></a>
    <h3>
     Edit Stock Form
    </h3>
    <form action="inventory_edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myform" method="post">
    <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
      <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Product Name</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
<input name="product_name" type="text" id="product_name" size="64" value='<?php echo $product_name; ?>' />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Product Price</td>
        <td><label>
          &pound;
          <input name="price" type="text" id="price" size="12" value='<?php echo $price ?>' />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Category</td>
        <td><label>
          <select name="category" id="category">

<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT category_Name FROM category");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo '<option>' . $row['category_Name'] . "</option>";

}

?>
</select>
        </label></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="right">Product Details</td>
        <td><label>
          <textarea name="details" id="details" cols="64" rows="5"><?php echo $details; ?></textarea>
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Product Image</td>
        <td><label>
          <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Number of Stock:</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <input name="stock" type="text" id="stock" size="12" value="<?php echo $stock; ?>" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>       
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label>
          <input name="thisID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $targetID; ?>" />
          <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Make Changes" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <br />
  <br />

</center>

      </div>
  <div id="content_bottom"></div>
  <br />
</div>
</div>


  </div>
  <?php include_once("../customer/template_footer.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a headache - it's actually why I went for a (free) off-the-shelf solution when I was doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem, that you first fill the `$id`, `$product_name`, etc. variables with currently edited product, but then you fill it again in the part of code, which does the listing.

Comment: It seems to show the $details for each different product though, everything else does not seem to show correctly.

Comment: @user3411002 yeah, its because `$details` are filled only in the "edit part", but not in the "listing part", so value of `$details` is always correct, but the others are overwritten by the "listing part"

Comment: I dont understand this lol, the rest is coded in the same way as the details part yet does not work or change properly.

Comment: @user3411002 i try to explain it once more:
You have variable `$product_name` (for example).
The code goes to line, where you get the data for currently edited product (`$product_name = $row["product_name"];`).
But then the code goes to the `while` cycle, which overwrites the value in `$product_name`.

Comment: Oh understand, its that last block causing the problem. when i do remove it everything works fine but the stock list doesnt show get an error. Will try to fix this myself.